# Wordpress | Imagen incorrecta seleccionada por facebook al compartir una entrada o post

Tags: wordpress, facebook, redes-sociales

Buenas.
Veréis, me está trayendo de cabeza esto.
Primero el problema. He probado con 2 plugins de redes sociales de los que añaden botones para compartir articulos o posts en Wordpress.
Al darle a compartir en Facebook elije una imagen que no corresponde con la que debería elegir que sería la imagen principal de la entrada aunque titulo y el Excerpt si los coge bien.

He probado con la solución para probar simplemente a poner en la cabecera

```
<meta property="og:image" content="[enlace-imagen]" /> (sin los corchetes).
```

Esto no funcionó.

He buscado en el siguiente enlace y he probado las 2 
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-facebook-incorrect-thumbnail-issue-in-wordpress/
La primera que es con el plugin Yoast SEO subir en cada entrada individualmente la imagen que quieres que Facebook coja al compartir el post y no funciona tampoco.
He probado la ultima opción que es la de usar el Debugger Tool de Facebook y no ha servido de nada.

No sé ya como hacer para que me coja la imagen del artículo. Tengo que especificar algo en el código del tema de wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta property="og:image" content="[enlace-imagen]" />
```

En *[enlace-imagen]* debe ir la imagen destacada del post.

Algo como:

```
the_post_thumbnail_url('thumbnail')
```

Entonces debe ser:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('caravanas'); ?>" />
```

Si quieres dame el link del sitio yo veo que ocurre y te ayudo a solucionar.